How to create a paragraph with multiple columns which has "fixed height" and "width by content"?
I'm trying to build a horizontal page layout with images and texts. Some texts are quite large and have to be split into columns, so I use CSS "columns". I want my text container to take 100% of window height and auto width based on the text content. Is it possible?
I'm trying this but my text container renders as wide as the window (probably because it is "inline block").
I'm getting this

And this

But want this (adaptable to any screen & text size)



<!DOCTYPE html><html>
<head>
    <style>
        * {
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
        }   

        body {
            white-space: nowrap;
            padding: 5vh;
            > div, p {
                height: 90vh;
                display: inline-block;
                vertical-align: top;
            }
            div {
                background-color: black;
                aspect-ratio: 2 / 5;
            }
            p {
                columns: 20vw auto;
                column-fill: auto;
                white-space: wrap;
                background-color: #ccc;
            }
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div></div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    <div></div>
</body>
</html>




Can you provide a visual sketch of your goal? Can you include an reproducible, minimal example? You talk about large content, but your example has only 4 words of text - and now I'm wondering whether you're asking about the text container width only or all of the stuff you mentioned (possibly only as context?).

If the text container is supposed to take the full height, why do you define height as 90vh?

You can use the editors "snippet" to include the code as a snippet that can render the result.

Don't think this is possible as it stands. You can get close but not everything AFAICT. https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/vYwmGej

Added screenshots and longer text to snippet, please take a look

Try this code:


* {
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
        }   

        body {
            white-space: nowrap;
            padding: 5vh;
            > div, p {
                height: 90vh;
                display: inline-block;
                vertical-align: top;
            }
            div {
                background-color: black;
                aspect-ratio: 2 / 5;
            }
            p {
                /* you can always change these values based upon your content*/
                columns: 20vw auto;
                
                /*change this value for column-fill*/
                column-fill: balance-all;
                white-space: wrap;
                background-color: #ccc;
            }
        }
<div></div>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
    <div></div>



Explanation:
With "column-fill: balance-all" set, Content is equally divided between columns.
Refer:
MDN Web Docs - Column Fill Documentation
I hope this helps.
